# Некорректная работа GET запроса контроллера API на ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, api, list, asp.net-core, linq

Вот такой код работает:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Product>> Get()
{
    return db.Products.ToList();
}
```

Но если я хочу присвоить связанные данные то приходит статус 500. Вот например код который не работает:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Product>> Get()
{
    List<Product> products =  db.Products.ToList();
    foreach (var p in products)
    {
        p.ProductСharacteristics =  db.ProductСharacteristics.Where(t => p.Id == t.ProductId).ToList();
    }
    return db.Products.ToList();
}
```

Вот модели:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LatinName { get; set; }
    public string ShortInfo { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }

    public List<ProductСharacteristic> ProductСharacteristics { get; set; }
    public Product()
    {
        ProductСharacteristics = new List<ProductСharacteristic>();
    }
}

public class ProductСharacteristic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Main { get; set; }
    public string Minor { get; set; }


    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Вот контроллер:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ProductController : ControllerBase
{
    ProductsContext db;

    public ProductController(ProductsContext context)
    {
        db = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Product>> Get()
    {
        List<Product> products =  db.Products.ToList();
        foreach (var p in products)
        {
            p.ProductСharacteristics =  db.ProductСharacteristics.Where(t => p.Id == t.ProductId).ToList();
        }
        return db.Products.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: текст ошибки есть?

Comment: ещё не очень понятен код, что вы пишете. Что вам мешает сделать `return db.Products.Include(p=>p.ProductСharacteristics).ToList();` ?

Comment: Закомментируйте в PC свойство Product и посмотрите, что будет.

Comment: Конечно есть текст ошибки, просто для этого надо в браузере открыть отладчик, посмотреть на закладку "сеть", найти нужный запрос, а потом посмотреть что в Responce прислано.

Comment: А ответ не надо вписывать в сам вопрос, его надо постить отдельно. Удалил, поправил форматирование.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Более лаконичным и правильным будет указать EF через навигационное свойство `ProductСharacteristics` необходимость загрузки в результирующий список продуктов зависимого содержимого. Например, это можно сделать так:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Product>> Get()
{
    return db.Products.Include(p => p.ProductСharacteristics).ToList();
}
```